# Showing that the square of a partial isometry is not zero

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm reading a paper and the paper seems to imply the following is obvious:

Let $S$ be a semigroup of partial isometries and suppose that $R$ is a minimal projection in the set $P(S) \cup Q(S)$ where $P(S)$ [respectively $Q(S)$] denotes the initial projections [final projections] of elements of $S$. Suppose $R=Q_A$ for some $A \in S$ and $P_A R \ne 0$ then $A^2$ is not $0$.

I don't see how this follows - nor do I see how to attack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A^2=0$, this means that the range of $A$ is contained in the kernel of $A$. This means that $(I-P_A)Q_A=Q_A$, or $P_AQ_A=0$.

Comment: Thanks much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!